# How to deploy multiple virtual machines to single cloud service with the new Resource Manager model programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

Curently I am deploying multiple VMs to single cloud service using this code:

```
private async Task CreateVirtualMachine()
    {
        DeploymentGetResponse deploymentResponse = await _computeManagementClient.Deployments.GetBySlotAsync("myservicename", DeploymentSlot.Production);

        if (deploymentResponse == null)
        {
            var parameters = new VirtualMachineCreateDeploymentParameters
            {
                DeploymentSlot = DeploymentSlot.Production,
                Name = "mservicename",
                Label = "myservicename"
            };

            parameters.Roles.Add(new Role
            {
                OSVirtualHardDisk = new OSVirtualHardDisk
                {
                    HostCaching = VirtualHardDiskHostCaching.ReadWrite,
                    SourceImageName = "imagename"
                },

                RoleName = "vmname",
                RoleType = VirtualMachineRoleType.PersistentVMRole.ToString(),
                RoleSize = VirtualMachineRoleSize.Small,
                ProvisionGuestAgent = true
            });

            parameters.Roles[0].ConfigurationSets.Add(new ConfigurationSet
            {
                ComputerName = "vmname",
                ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.LinuxProvisioningConfiguration,
                HostName = "vmname",
                AdminUserName = "adminusername",
                AdminPassword = "adminpass",
                UserName = "username",
                UserPassword = "userpass",
                DisableSshPasswordAuthentication = false,

            });

            parameters.Roles[0].ConfigurationSets.Add(new ConfigurationSet
            {
                ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.NetworkConfiguration,
                InputEndpoints = new List<InputEndpoint>()
                {
                    new InputEndpoint()
                    {
                        Name = "HTTP",
                        Protocol = InputEndpointTransportProtocol.Tcp,
                        LocalPort =  80,
                        Port = 80
                    }
                }
            });

            var response = await _computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.CreateDeploymentAsync("mservicename", parameters);

        }
        else
        {
            var createParameters = new VirtualMachineCreateParameters
            {
                OSVirtualHardDisk = new OSVirtualHardDisk
                {
                    HostCaching = VirtualHardDiskHostCaching.ReadWrite,
                    SourceImageName = "imagename"
                },

                RoleName = "vmname",
                RoleSize = VirtualMachineRoleSize.Small,
                ProvisionGuestAgent = true,

                ConfigurationSets = new List<ConfigurationSet>
            {
                new ConfigurationSet
                {

                    ComputerName = "vmname",
                    ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.LinuxProvisioningConfiguration,
                    HostName = "vmname",
                    AdminUserName = "adminusername",
                    AdminPassword = "adminpass",
                    UserName = "username",
                    UserPassword = "userpass",
                    DisableSshPasswordAuthentication = false
                },
                new ConfigurationSet
                {
                    ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.NetworkConfiguration,
                    InputEndpoints = new List<InputEndpoint>()
                    {
                        new InputEndpoint()
                        {
                            Name = "HTTP",
                            Protocol = InputEndpointTransportProtocol.Tcp,
                            LocalPort =  81,
                            Port = 81
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            };

            var responseCreate = await _computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.CreateAsync("mservicename", deploymentResponse.Name, createParameters);

        }
    }
```

How can this be done using new Resource Manager? I am working in Visual Studio 2015, MVC application.

Problem is that when deploying multiple VMs to cloud service, all of VMs have same domain/ip. But I want that every VM has it's own domain. I heard that this can be done with Resource Manager, but realy dont know exactly what Resource Manager is, or how to use it.

Also, I am aware that deploying each VM to single cloud service would give unique domain name to each VM, but that means I must create new cloud service for every virtual machine, and what I really need is to deploy multiple vm's to single cloud service.

Can this be done with Resource management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new resource manager model has no concept of cloud services, you simply deploy a VM into a virtual network and connect it directly to the internet via a public IP address. You can then attach any domain name you want to that public IP.

It is impossible to create a cloud service within resource management.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Wouldn't Virtual Machines (Classic) still be using a backing cloud service?

Comment: @Thraka Virtual Machines (Classic) are Azure Service Management (ASM) VMs and not ARM (v2) VMs - ASM uses cloud services, ARM doesn't

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous answer, the cloud service concept doesn't exist for the Resource Manager deployment model. This article provides an overview of some of the ways you can deploy multiple virtual machines in the same resource group: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-multiple-vms/